# Setting additional properties based on other property values in JSON schema

Tags: json, jsonschema, json-schema-validator

I want to set some of the properties of a filter-item based on the value of an existing property. If the property `Type` has the value `Range` then the properties `From` and `To` should be added to the filterItem. Else the rest of the properties should be an array of `FilterValues`. I tried to set the properties with if and else, but it seems like I am missing on something.

The parts of my JSON schema:

```
"Filter": {
              "type": [
                "array",
                "null"
              ],
              "items": {
                "$ref": "#/definitions/filterItem"
              },
              "additionalProperties": false
            }
___________________________________________________

"filterItem": {
      "type": "object",
      "properties": {
        "AttributeCode": {
          "type": "string",
          "pattern": "^[a-z0-9_-]+$"
        },
        "Typ": {
          "type": "string"
        },
        "if": {
          "properties": {
            "Typ": {
              "const": "Range"
            }
          }
        },
        "then": {
          "properties": {
            "From": {
              "type": "integer",
              "minLength": 1
            },
            "To": {
              "type": "integer",
              "minLength": 1
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        },
        "else": {
          "properties": {
            "FilterValues": {
              "type": "array",
              "items": {
                "type": "string",
                "pattern": "^[a-z0-9_-]+$"
              }
            }
          },
          "additionalProperties": false
        }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
```

The validator shows that the properties are not following my schema (Screenshot):
[validator](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8yHD.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two major issues with your schema, how you use `if`-`then`-`else` and how you use `addtionalProperties`.

#### `if`-`then`-`else`

JSON Schema keywords can only appear in the context of a schema. `properties` defines an object whose values are a schema. `properties` itself is not a schema.

```
"properties": {
  "foo": { ... }
  "if": { ... },
  "then": { ... }
}
```

This doesn't define one property, "foo", plus a conditional. It defines three properties: "foo", "if", "then". You need to bring your conditional up a level for it to be recognized by the validator.

```
"properties": {
  "foo": { ... }
},
"if": { ... }
"then": { ... }
```

Otherwise, you're using `if`-`then`-`else` properly. It's just in the wrong place.

#### `additionalProperties`

Once you get your `if`-`then`-`else` in the right place, you'll notice that you get a bunch of `additionalProperties` errors. `additionalProperties` can take into account only the `properties` and `patternProperties` keywords in the same place in the schema.

```
{
  "allOf": [
    {
      "properties": {
        "foo": { ... }
      }
    },
    {
      "properties": {
        "bar": { ... }
      },
      "additionalProperties": false
    }
  ]
}
```

`/allOf/1/additionalProperties` can only take into account `/allOf/1/properties`, not `/allOf/0/properties`. So, `{ "foo": 1, "bar": 2 }` will be invalid because "foo" is not defined in `/allOf/1/properties`.

There are a couple ways to deal with this. The preferred way is to simply not use `additionalProperties`. Ignore additional properties instead of forbidding them. This is best for evolvable schemas, but depending on the domain, it's not always feasible.

To use `additionalProperties` effectively, you need all possible property names under the same `properties` keyword.

```
"properties": {
  "foo": { ... },
  "bar": { ... }
},
"required": ["foo"],
"additionalProperties": false,
"if": {
  "properties": {
    "foo": { "const": 1 }
  },
  "required": ["foo"]
},
"then": { "required": ["bar"] }
```

This is one possible approach. "bar" is only expected if "foo" is 1, but "bar" is defined at the top and only required if the conditional passes. Not only does this make `additionalProperties` work as you expect, it's also easier to read because all of the property definitions are in one place and the conditional schemas are minimal.

At this point you might be concerned that including "bar" when "foo" is not 1 does not throw an error. Again, I'd encourage you to ignore the additional property rather than forbid it if your domain allows. But, if you really need to you can use `else` to forbid the extra field.

```
"else": { "not": { "required": ["bar"] } }
```

Be careful not to be confused by the words in that schema. It doesn't mean "not required" which sounds like "optional", it means "forbidden".

Comment: Thank you very much for your detailed answer, Jason! I put the statement on the correct lvl and used additionalProperties as you mentioned. This now does the exact thing I want it to do :) cheers!